# Подчёркиваются русские слова в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Всем доброго времени суток. В среде разработке Visual Studio подчёркиваются русские слова. Как это исправить? Очень режет глаза.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой кодировке файл? UTF8 или 1251? Что если навести мышку на стрелочку с исправлением? Какое сообщение? В 8й строке почему-то не подчёркнуто - может какое расширение левое стоит?

Comment: @Qwertiy У меня стоит ReSharper

Comment: Добавьте словарь с рус. языком в решарпер, об этом написано в [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Spell_Checking.html#respeller-dictionaries).